# k-array tree to produce adjacency matrix

Tags: java, tree

Hi I am trying to implement k-array tree whose output is in the form of adjacent matrix using Java. Input parameters given are 
k=number of child for each node and 
d= depth of tree (height).

Given these parameter I have to generate adjacent matrix (written on file) of the k-array tree. can you please guide me to implement this?

I already had a look at the following links and I am not able to follow because I am Java beginner. so can you someone please guide me to this?

http://vivin.net/2010/01/30/generic-n-ary-tree-in-java/

http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2006/05/java-data-structure-generic-tree.html

Comment: I am in need of this implementation for my research work and this is not my assignment. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an implementation of a [k-ary tree](https://github.com/vivin/tree/blob/master/src/main/java/net/vivin/collections/KAryTree.java) (it is very similar to my n-ary tree implementation that you linked to). It is not complete, but it should give you enough to start on.

To generate an adjacency matrix, you would need a two-dimensional array with dimensions `n x k`. You would then have to traverse the tree and populate the adjacency matrix. A row `i` would correspond to node `i` and `matrix[i][0]` to `matrix[i][k - 1]` would contain references to the `k` children of node `i`. Of course, the order of the nodes in the adjacency matrix would depend on your method of traversal.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I am beginner so can you guide me on where to start from, because I don't see any "static void main()". where do I give input value such as K and d?

Comment: @Nesh That question is far too broad, I'm afraid. You're going to have to import this library or simply copy over the classes you need. You will be instantiating objects of this class from your `main()`. It really depends on your implementation.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. Can i kindly request you to give me an example on how to use it? then I can take it over from there.

Comment: some thing like this 
https://github.com/c05mic/GenericN-aryTree/blob/master/README.txt

here he has given an example and so i can understand it better. can you please make something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code provided by @VivinPaliath, I added a simple (dirty) script which can generate the adjacency matrix, where **k** controls the number of children and **d** the depth of the tree. The type of **KAryTreeNode** is set to Integer because it stores the index of the node.

The output is printed to the console. The classes **AbstractNode**, **AbstractTree**, **KAryTree**, **KAryTreeNode**, **Node**, **Tree** and **TreeTraversalOrder** need to be added to the project. These classes can be found in @VivinPaliath's Github repository.

```
public class KAryTreeGenerator {

    public static Integer index = 0;

    public static void populate(KAryTreeNode<Integer> node, int height, int k) {
        if (height == 0) {
            // nothing more to do
        } else {

            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
                node.addChild(new KAryTreeNode<>(k, index));
                index = index + 1;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
                populate(node.getChildAt(i), height - 1, k);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int k = 3; // number of children
        int d = 3; // depth

        KAryTreeNode<Integer> root = new KAryTreeNode<>(k, index);
        index = index + 1;

        KAryTree<Integer> tree = new KAryTree<>(k, root);

        d = d - 1;
        populate(tree.root, d, k);

        int size = (int)((Math.pow((double)k, (double)(d+1) ) - 1)/(k - 1));

        int[][] adjacencyMatrix = new int[size][size];

        List<KAryTreeNode<Integer>> queue = new LinkedList<>();

        queue.add(root);

        while(!queue.isEmpty()) {

            KAryTreeNode<Integer> parent = queue.remove(0);

            List<KAryTreeNode<Integer>> children = parent.getChildren();

            for(KAryTreeNode<Integer> child: children) {
                // adjacencyMatrix[child.data][parent.data] = -1; //shows the parent in the matrix
                adjacencyMatrix[parent.data][child.data] = 1;
            }
            queue.addAll(children);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < adjacencyMatrix.length; i++) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append(Arrays.toString(adjacencyMatrix[i]));
            builder.deleteCharAt(0);
            builder.deleteCharAt(builder.toString().length()-1);
            System.out.println(builder.toString());
        }
    }
}
```